# Algorithm to replace integers in array by the nearest bigger integer on their right

Tags: arrays, algorithm, comparison

How do you solve this problem in O(n) time?

Given an unsorted array of integers, design algorithms to transform the array such that the integers are replaced by the nearest bigger integer on their right. If there is no bigger integer on its right, the integer remains the same. For example, the following array of integers

```
2 1 4 5 3 6 7 9 4 8
```

should become

```
4 4 5 6 6 7 9 9 8 8
```

Comment: Are you sure there is O(n) solution?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 there is. the algorithm is actually quite trivial

Comment: @paul If you mean the algorithm provided by orlp, then there should be a misunderstanding.

Comment: @cppgondnler it's actually pretty close. Or to be more precise, the algorithm you presented **should** do the job, if implemented properly, except for the fact that there's an additional storage required for elements that were  traversed and replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Init Stack of integers
- From left to right.
- Pop from stack while element is smaller, and replace it with the current
- Add id of element to stack

Note that the stack will be strictly decreasing. And that each element is popped/added max 1 time. Hence `O(N)`

Example code in Python:

```
l = [2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 9, 4, 8]
s = [0]
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    while s and l[i] > l[s[-1]]:
        l[s.pop()] = l[i]
    s.append(i)
```

Comment: You were a minute earlier and properly explained it.